# UserControl databinding inside ListView fails

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, user-controls

I have a custom control, here simplified:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.TestControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With usage:

```
<local:TestControl Grid.Row="0">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Border>
</local:TestControl>
```

So far so good, that works.

However, when used as part of a DataTemplate for a ListView, the binding no longer works:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
            <local:TestControl>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </local:TestControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

What incantations are needed to make the databinding above work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an infinite loop.
The `UserControl` already is a `ContentControl` as it derives from it. So as long as you don't override its `ControlTemplate`, you should not add a `ContentPresenter` to it, which binds to the `TemplatedParent` while being used inside a template.

The trigger of this misery is the `TemplatedParent` binding. The `TestControl` is part of a template. The template is applied to the `ListViewItem`, which is therefore the templated parent of `TestControl`.

Now the value of the binding source of the `ContentPresenter` inside the `TestControl` is the value of the `ListViewItem.Content` property, which holds the `TestControl` itself. This way you add the templated parent `ListViewItem.Content`, which is the `TestControl`, to the `ContentPresenter` of `TestControl`, which now contains the same `TestControl` (itself), which binds the templated parent `ListViewItem.Content`, which is the `TestControl`, to the `ContentPresenter` of `TestControl`, which now contains the same `TestControl` (itself), which binds the templated parent... StackOverflow.

If you want to use the `UserControl` like a `ContentControl` i.e. to display the visuals of other "external" controls, then use it like the `ContentCobtrol` it is:

**TestControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestControl">
</UserControl>
```

**DataTemplate**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
  <local:TestControl>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=OneWay}"/>
  </local:TestControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Or if the content is more complex and advanced than simple presentation, you should override the `ControlTemplate`:

**TestControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestControl">
  <UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TreeIndex">
      <Border>
        <Grid>
          ...
          <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </Grid>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

**DataTemplate**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
  <local:TestControl>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=OneWay}"/>
  </local:TestControl>
</DataTemplate>
```